# Matplotlib animation save method returns creates static image with unexpected number of frames

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas, matplotlib-animation

Trying to work with animation module of matplotlib in order to create an animation of grid changes.
Libraries used.

```
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Creating grid with geopandas (full image of the grid could be seen with the `grid.plot(edgecolor = 'white')` command):

```
xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax = -2, -2, 2, 2
length = 0.1
wide = 0.1
columns = list(np.arange(int(np.floor(xmin)), int(np.ceil(xmax)), wide))
rows = list(np.arange(int(np.floor(ymin)), int(np.ceil(ymax)), length))
rows.reverse()
grid = gpd.GeoDataFrame(columns = ['geometry'])
for row in rows:
    for column in columns:
        grid.loc[len(grid)]=Polygon([(column, row), (column + wide, row), (column + wide, row - length), (column, row - length)])
```

Function to animate appearance of each polygon:

```
def update_grid_next(curr):
    ax = plt.gca()

    ax.axis([-2, 2, -2.1, 1.9])
    ax.annotate('n = %s'%curr, [-2, -2])


    ax.plot(*grid.geometry[curr].exterior.xy, color = 'b')
    ax.fill(*grid.geometry[curr].exterior.xy, alpha=0.5, fc='r', ec='none')
```

When I run the following code, animation is shown in Jupyter Notebook in a way I expected (more or less):

```
%matplotlib
fig = plt.figure()
a = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_grid_next, interval=50, frames = range(75))
```

One by one polygons appear on a plot.
However, when I try to save video with `a.save(r'C:\Users\fasbo\k.mp4')`, matplotlib creates [static](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4HNL.png) image with surprising number of frames recorded/captured.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you may need to use the `init_func` argument in `FuncAnimation`, which is the function used to draw a clear frame. The update function is meant to update objects in the figure instead of plotting more.

[Here](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/) is a small tutorial on how to use the update and init functions. If you're learning how to make animations, I'd advise you to start with something simple first.